# Excel VBA: Copy and paste duplicate values from other cell

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I have an excel file with two columns. 
Excel screenshot below:

[image]

What I want is an Excel VBA that will read all duplicate values and if the cell beside it is blank, value from the other duplicate account will be pasted in the blank cell.
Expected result:

[image]

I'm not good with Excel VBA so I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could try this

```
Sub Main()
    With Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, XlTextValues).Offset(,1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Where

- the 1st SpecialCells selects column A cells with some text value
- the Offset selects their corresponding cells in next column to the right (i.e column B)
- the 2nd SpecialCells selects empty cells in this latter range

Comment: Hi, @user3598756. Your code also worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to accept the answer with the code you actually chose.

Comment: @user3445540, please reward by accepting it the answer that you actually resolved to use in your code

Answer (score 2):

A starting point is to loop through each value and compare it to each value in the column:

```
Sub FillDuplicates()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column A

For x = 1 To lastrow
    If Cells(x, 2).Value <> "" Then 'Check if cell in column B is empty
        For y = 1 To lastrow
            If Cells(y, 1).Value = Cells(x, 1).Value Then 'Compares cell against each value in column A
                Cells(y, 2).Value = Cells(x, 2).Value 'If matches, add value in column B
            End If
        Next y
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```